# SWIG issues with Python 3.7 and excess_args

Tags: c++, python-3.x, swig

I have some code C++ code for an extension module that I just upgraded from Python2.7.11 with an older SWIG to python3.7.1 with SWIG 3.0.12. I am experiencing an issue similar to https://bugs.python.org/issue34495, only its `Py_None` and not `nullptr`. The generated code in `SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance` calls `tp_new` with `Py_None` for the 2nd and 3rd argument.

```
SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance(SwigPyClientData *data, PyObject *swig_this)
{
    ...
    #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
    inst = ((PyTypeObject*) data->newargs)->tp_new((PyTypeObject*) data->newargs, Py_None, Py_None);
```

which leads to a `object_new` call with both `args` and `kwds` pointing to `Py_None`

```
object_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    if (excess_args(args, kwds)) {
```

and then calls `excess_args` with `args` and `kwds`

```
excess_args(PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    return PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args) ||
        (kwds && PyDict_Check(kwds) && PyDict_GET_SIZE(kwds));
```

where `PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args)` chokes on the `Py_None`.

Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found [this issue](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1321) on SWIGs GitHub page. Apparently the problem has been fixed but no new version with the fix released.

**Udpate**

Apparently an update is not necessary. I replaced the `LIb\python\pyrun.swg` with the current version from [github](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/python/pyrun.swg). That solved my problems. In case someone finds that too risky, one can just patch the problematic code section in `SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance`, replacing

```
SWIGRUNTIME PyObject* 
SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance(SwigPyClientData *data, PyObject *swig_this)
{
     ...
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
    inst = ((PyTypeObject*) data->newargs)->tp_new((PyTypeObject*) data->newargs, Py_None, Py_None);
    ...
}
```

with this

```
SWIGRUNTIME PyObject* 
SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance(SwigPyClientData *data, PyObject *swig_this)
{
     ...
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
    PyObject *empty_args = PyTuple_New(0);
    if (empty_args) {
      inst = ((PyTypeObject *)data->newargs)->tp_new((PyTypeObject *)data->newargs, empty_args, Py_None);
      Py_DECREF(empty_args);
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

or just replace the whole function with the fixed version.